# Finding the IP address in Adobe AIR

Tags: adobe, air, ip-address

How to know the IP address of the system in which the AIR application is currently running, Or
how to restrict the usage of AIR application for a particular country?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code, it works for me.

```
import flash.net.InterfaceAddress;
import flash.net.NetworkInterface;

var netInterfaces:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
var addresses:Vector.<InterfaceAddress> = netInterfaces[0].addresses;
ipAddress = addresses[0].address;
```

Comment: this is wrong #jhloke your code only shows local ip address not what the question intends... I know this because I am looking for the answer also! :)

Comment: Note that this does not work on mobile does, only desktop and smart tv