# Get IP Address of an AIR 1.0 application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

I need to find the IP Address of the system my AIR App is running. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679215/finding-the-ip-address-in-adobe-air). But the solution is with SDK version higher than 3.5 it seems. Can this be done using Flex 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the IP Address in an AIR 1.0 App; it is possible.  But, tedious.

First, you have to use a tool such as [Merapi](http://code.google.com/p/merapi/).  Merapi will run as a "server" on the clients machine.  You can access that server using the RemoteObject tag.  So, you can write native Java code to get the IP address, expose that code as a service and access that service via the Merapi project.

You'll have to create your own installer to make this work; to install Merapi in the client machine as part of the app install.

I've done something similar using the [WebORB .NET version](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html), although we used it to access an MS Access database.  It's a pain.  I would not recommend this approach lightly.

Comment: whoa, thats a lot of stuff for getting the ip address :)

Comment: Agreed! Perhaps I should have asked why the AIR ap needs the system's IP Address.  Your remote services should be able to get the IP address as a CGI variable as part of the request.

Comment: Yeah, i just talked with my TL. Initially i was to send the ip address to the server to open a socket and do communication. But we just found out that sending the ip is redundant as you pointed out - the Server already has the IP.

Comment: I have chosen this to be the answer because my question was specifically about getting the IP in AIR 1.0. And it is not easy to accomplish :)

Answer (score 2):

The link you've found isn't related to Flex SDK version but related to AIR SDK and runtime version. The code used in the link requires AIR ADK 2 (because of `NetworkInterface` usage). You can use AIR 2 SDK with Flex SDK 3.5 very easily. Follow [these instructions](http://zaid.aldabbagh.net/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_Adobe_AIR_2_SDK_with_Flex_3.5_SDK) for example.

Comment: With AIR 1.0 it is impossible. `Vector` class is available since 1.5 and `NetworkInterface` since 2.0.

Comment: :) i meant way other than using `NetworkInterface`, And i didnt know `Vector` was part of 1.0, i thought it was in 2.0 too...

Comment: `Vector` is in 1.5, not 1.0. And what about other ways to determine IP I don't know them :(

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but [**Socket**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) and its property **localAddress** can be used to get local IP for Adobe Air 1.0

[image]

*Supported Air Version*

API doc says **AIR 1.0**, and Header say **Air 2.6 and earlier**

Hopes that helps

Comment: Its only available in air 2.0 :(

Comment: Plz see link it says "Runtime Versions: AIR 1.0, Flash Player 9, Flash Lite 4"

Comment: nope, it says "AIR 2.7 and earlier, Flash Player 10.3 and earlier, Flash Lite 4". anyway, i can't find that property for a `Socket` object in flex builder 3

Comment: ya as you says "AIR 2.7 and earlier" written in header and api says Air1.0 min

Comment: hey i think that line is for the Class. Check http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#localAddress , it says "Runtime Versions: AIR 2" against `localAddress`.

Comment: The header is a filter for the documentation; and is not class specific.  However, the runtime versions as part of the class seems to be the answer looking for.